# How would you make a culture that discouraged polyamory even among elites?

Tags: fantasy-races, gods, relationships

I've read a lot of harem stories, and they often have things set up to make harems even more likely, such as skewed gender ratios, eliminating jealousy, religious support and such.

I am writing a story where the opposite is true, where a god is making a world where polyamory is strongly discouraged. But I face a problem- how do you discourage such for even the rich? The rich often have a lot of insulation from social rules and values, have the wealth to support multiple partners, and can use money to pressure poor people to join their sex group.

The god values free will, and doesn't want to tweak humans much far beyond what happens on earth. They're fine going to any extreme of a society, but they don't want to go so far as to program humans to perform like a marionette, or do something like people fuse into one being when they mate, or to have angels patrol and smite anyone who sleeps outside of their relationship, or to eliminate the sex drive.

An ideal answer will explain how to set up a humanish society or a people which has mostly people having one partner, even among the rich, and will be able to scale up to city or nation size.

Comment: Is serial monogamy acceptable (ie once a relationship is concluded each partner is free to form a new monogamous relationship) and if so, how often are people free to change relationship?  Or is the objective for each person to have only either lifetime monogamy or abstinence?

Comment: Fast enough serial monogamy is effectively polyamory. Their general goal is that most people stay in a relationship for most of their lives, excepting abuse and such. They can move on after their partner is dead.

Comment: Questions asking "how to build X" are very broad. Literally any method of construction is a valid answer. What can you tell us about your specific world? What constraints have you imposed on yourself that prevent you from just saying "polyamory is discouraged in my culture."?

Comment: It also seems like you're mixing up polgamy, (group marriages), and polyamory (multiple intimate relationships, with the consent of all involved).

Comment: If your achieving this by way of a god it seems like you simply remove the temptation by divine decree.  Is it a fantasy race or a divinely altered human?

Comment: You said both "polyamory" and "harem." Please be specific, are you looking for a way to avoid polyamorous marriages or are you really asking, "how do I create a society that never experiences out-of-wedlock sexual relationships?" The repercussions behind that statement are staggering. You never so much as kiss any date that won't become your spouse and extramarital affairs never happen. Without the use of an external force (aka, lightning bolts) to compel behavior, I have a hard time suspending my disbelief for that one. The species must survive, and you're subverting the motivation to do so.

Comment: I mentioned my constraints in the post- not massively violating free will or human biology, and being effective on the rich. And, avoiding polyamory is more the issue- they don't especially care about marriage.

As I noted, the rich often have some insulation from social rules, and the god doesn't want to enforce the rule with divine smites. They can certainly decree that polyamory is forbidden, but they want to set up a society/ magic/ the species in a way that discourages polyamory so they don't need to constantly intervene to fix things.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this question really about [polyamory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyamory), or is this word being used with an unspecified meaning different from the meaning it has in the real world? Because if the question really means polyamory, then our real world is a world where polyamory is . . . exotic. (And no, serial monogamy is not polyamory. By definition, polyamory requires multiple consenting partners which are all aware of the others and are OK with it.)

Comment: The question is about polyamory as noted. I don't want to constrain the question to people who don't have a deep understanding of the nuances of polyamory, but the question's main goal is discouraging people from having multiple partners at the same time who know about each other.

Comment: I would note that most answers have been written with a more popular culture definition of polyamory. The polyamorous community has a particular definition of polyamory, and pop culture's definition is a bit broader. I would enjoy an answer from someone who used a stricter definition of polyamory, but if most of my answers are around cheating or enforcing monogamy or any sort of open relationship I am fine working with that.

Comment: @NepeneNep Do you mean several sexual partners or several romantic partners? Typically having the odd orgy does not make you a polyamour. Even if you "pressure poor people to join their sex group".

Comment: So your question boils down to "how do you make a culture that discourage refrigerator-fetishist-o-sexuals"? The bigger question is, of course, in what circumstances could the opposite ever be true? It's a fringe notion that afflicts marginal people who soon learn that it contradicts human nature so thoroughly that it falls apart in a few short years and is mocked by mainstream society far longer than it ever lived on as a fad.

Comment: The male loses his penis during sex, and has to wait 30 days for it to grow back.

Comment: I'm not sure how sustainable it would be not having multiple consensual partners and having orgies. If anyone caught feelings then the god would be unhappy. That said, I am open to an answer which addresses how people should make regular use of orgies but still just have a single romantic partner who is the only one they have a relationship with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 historically proven methods:

1. Religion. Many religions, at least ostensibly, are very strict about monogamy. It doesn't always works well, and the rich and powerful find ways around it, but when religion is strong, monogamy is enforced quite well. Even kings had to abide by the rules of their marriages.
2. Gender rights. Polyamory usually occurs when one of the spouses (typically the husband) has disproportional amount of power. This way he doesn't need to worry too much about his wife discovering his affairs. However, when the spouse is not just a consort, but a fully empowered partner, this calculation changes. On top of that, there may be "at fault" laws which penalize cheating - offended spouse could get an outsized share of property if the other spouse is found to be cheating.

Let's add one more option: taking advantage of divine powers.

3. Allergic reaction. In this world, sex with a new partner leads to a distinctly visible and uncomfortable, but not really harmful allergic reaction. After couple of weeks body adapts to the new partner and symptoms disappear, so this reaction is commonly known as "honeymoon rash". The reaction is very specific to intimate contact - it occurs very rarely if close contact in non-sexual. This reaction is very sensitive, so using barrier contraceptives does not prevent this reaction. This reaction is difficult to treat - existing anti-allergic medications help only a little. Also, the body can not adjust to more than one partners simultaneously, so engaging in polyamory leads to permanent rash.

Comment: History has proven that neither of those options will work for anything but a minor fraction of the population.

Comment: @Join JBH on Codidact - Huh? I thought this question is about [Polyamory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyamory), not mundane cheating.

Comment: The god is also against non consensual polyamory or sex, and would also dislike cheating, so this answer which discourages cheating is fine. And yeah, as Join JBH said, is there any way to make this more effective against the rich? They can tweak culture, biology, and magic freely within the constrains of humanish free will to enable better prevention of the rich.

Comment: *"Polyamory usually occurs when one of the spouses (typically husband) has disproportional amount of power":* This answer seems to imply a non-standard meaning of the word "[polyamory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyamory)".

Comment: @AlexP this is a topic for a long discussion, but considering that real world polyamory is often not a fully consensual polyamory (i.e. not all partners are actually willing to the same extent), I stand by my comment.

Comment: lol +1 for honeymoon rash

Comment: The honeymoon rash sounds like a pretty cool adaption to help enable this universe.

Comment: Honeymoon rash is an interesting thought, but it seems to me that this is something elites could easily escape, with something like cosmetics, a treatment, or even just plain ignoring it. It could even be considered a badge of honor. Also, it may become socially invisible because by nature it would always be visible in a substantial part of the population, depending on how frequently people change partners.

Comment: The god can make the rash impossible to cover up with cosmetics since they're omnipotent, and can make it quite hard to ignore so this works pretty well.

Answer (score 5):

#### First define polyamory!

Polygamy is the state of having multiple partners.  Partners need not necessarily be in love (as in a harem), and other partners do not necessarily know about each other (as in the long-distance traveller with wives in different cities).

Polyamory is a modern coinage though, and is normally defined as having multiple romantic partners who know of each other and approve.  It was specifically coined to be distinct from the potentially-unethical aspects of polygamy.  If you like, polyamory is polygamy done ethically!

Your question describes rich people using their money as a source of power to buy sex (a harem of slaves, or basic prostitution), or at the very least as the basis of a relationship (as with a courtesan or the modern "sugar daddy").  This is not polyamory, because regardless of whether there is realistic consent or not, the poorer person would not be with the richer person unless they were rich.

#### What stops polygamy and polyamory?

Look around you!  You're almost certainly living in a society where polygamy and polyamory aren't "normal".  All you need to do is look at why that is.  Some top answers would be:-

##### Religion

Traditional Christianity defines marriage as the union of one man and one woman, and says that any sex outside marriage is always a sin.  There's no scope for gay relationships, nor polyamory, nor polygamy, nor consensual sex work.  That's been the case in Western society for 1700 years, since Constantine adopted Christianity.  Sure, non-monogamous-heterosexual relationships have always happened, but religious and societal pressures have always put massive limits on them.  Even amongst the aristocracy, mistresses were largely kept somewhat secret, or at least "deniable".

##### Jealousy

Jealousy is a big issue, because not everyone has full compersion (the ability to genuinely enjoy seeing someone else enjoying themselves, even when it may negatively affect the amount of time you have with them).  It's often hard enough for couples to negotiate one half going out on their own to have a social meetup with friends, never mind negotiating an entire extra romantic relationship!  You really don't have to tweak humans that far before this becomes a major problem.  Of course that won't stop the "cheating" version of polygamy, but it would certainly put a hard stop on genuine polyamory.

##### Disease

Some sexually transmitted disease could be a possibility, but it needs to be properly dangerous.  Historically syphilis was a major issue, of course, but life was so "nasty, brutish and short" that a pandemic disease which only killed you slowly, on top of all the others which could kill you much more quickly, was not such a great concern.  Conversely the AIDS epidemic had a fairly significant effect on reducing promiscuity, because it was a relatively fast killer and other diseases were less prevalent.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd support the idea that romantic relationships don't count if money is involved. It's not in the normal definitions of polyamory.

Also, this answer doesn't really cover my key points, which are preventing it among the rich. As you note, they often had mistresses, and them being secret mistresses doesn't really please the god, since they can see all, and can see even secret mistresses.

Comment: @NepeneNep Polyamory is about the "amor" side. Sure, it's possible to fall in love with your mistress - but if the mistress won't stay if you don't pay her, then it's not mutual. And sure, they had mistresses - but they didn't have harems, so social pressure clearly did greatly reduce how much they could use their money that way. If you can see a massive reduction happening, you should be able to work out how to extend that further. The exact mechanism has to be plot-based though, and that's your job. :)

Comment: From what I've read of history, lords and kings often slept with maids, servants, mistresses, and their wife and so had a de facto harem. As such, I am doubtful that social pressure especially effective at reducing it. 

Also, many poly communities and this god don't see sex work as mutually exclusive to being polyamorous.

Comment: "Even amongst the aristocracy, mistresses were largely kept somewhat secret, or at least "deniable"." This is exactly what the questioner wanted to address - those mistresses. You seem to have simply blown them off as inevitable.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast No, I've described how even for people with effectively infinite resources, they were very much constrained. As I said above, if the OP wants conditions to be more constrained then it should be obvious to look at any existing constraints and simply make them tighter. Some degree of transgression *is* inevitable though, because the OP wants his world to remain human, and the nature of humans is to not follow rules perfectly all the time.

Answer (score 3):

### Dicrocoelium dendriticum

… Or a least a parasite with similar properties.

Dicrocoelium dendriticum is a parasite that switch hosts during its lifetime (from snails to ants then to herbivorous mammals). To achieve this last migration, **it forces ants to adopt a suicidal behavior**: climbing to the top of grass blade to be eaten…

Now imagine parasites, human symbionts living somewhere near our genitals. Everybody gets its own colony as these parasites are transmitted by birth. To ensure a good renewal of genes pool, this species “accepts” one other colony to mate with: the first it meets. Then, for a question of living space (intraspecific competition) the mixed colony don’t accept any other parasites. To be sure intruders will not try to invade the host body, these parasites force the host to adopt a social behavior : mating only with one partner (the one hosting the same mixed colony).

Comment: That works pretty well. So, any dalliances outside a stable relationship would cause the person disgust or bad health or suicidal behaviour. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: You are welcome. A strong disgust feeling is the better option here as symbiont parasites wouldn't have interrest in killing or weaken their host.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the male visual arousal mechanism and instill the same female commitment attachment.

Male arousal is a physical trait created by hormones, and seminal release needs to occur periodically or frustration occurs. This doesn’t happen in the female physiology.

Instead of visual arousal in males, your god alters the male attachment to be more alike to the female attachment.

Generally, the hormone situation should not need adjusting as long as there is at least *one* partner available, but now the partner is not chosen primarily by visual stimulation any more.

This maintains relationships but deters pornographic stimulation.

Side effects would be a “debeutification” of women as their visual seduction tools are taken away. Beauty won’t hold the same high place, and women will need to find a new social competition strategy.

There is no nice way to take a fully evolved society, make one single change, and guarantee all outcomes will be roses. There will be unintended consequences that your god will need to deal with:

Women will bear a higher burden in society as they won’t be able to buy as much with their looks. It could have negative effects in parenting as they will be more competitive in the workplace, increasing the number of children with superficial bonding with their parents.

Comment: They want to discourage polyamory for both men and women, so could this answer be extended to women somehow?

Comment: This answer doesn't really account for observed real-world behavior of people with female-style attraction who are attracted to women: namely, lesbians. While there _are_ general differences between us lesbians vs. straight men, non-monogamy is definitely still a thing in people with female-style attraction. Visual attraction is common too, although not as directly relevant as non-monogamy. (although there is a hormonal difference in how the libido works, things like pair-bonding seem to be driven by factors other than just one's current levels of T vs. E+P)

Comment: The unfortunate response is that the question is scoped to create a world “with mostly people having one partner,” and minimal divine intervention. An answer asking to solve for most or all LGBTQIA+ permutations *without* divine fiat, will form multiple real-world questions; each of those requiring [a detailed scope for how you will judge answers](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate), because there is no single school of thought forming our understanding of how these less common mechanisms work.

Comment: @NepeneNep In my opinion a commitment-based attachment should be gender indifferent, yes. Something closer to a child-parent attachment which ignores gender.

Answer (score 2):

Obs: this question seems to have a very loose definition of polyamory. As I understood, you just want monogamy, not harems or cheating, neither of which are polyamorous.

**Throw away human reproduction and start from scratch**

Biology shapes culture. Even today the social norms dictate monogamy, and across the world and history, while not strictly enforced monogamy, monogamy was the most common pairing as most men couldn't afford multiple spouses and women need support to take care of the her children.

However, since having more partners increases fitness, people try it anyway, specially high status individuals who probably can get away with breaking social norms. It is not because it will increase fitness, but because people who do it become more common over time in the population.

As it stand now, both sexes benefit from multiple partners. Males by quantity of offspring and females by having genetic diversity or sneaking in better genes than her social partner has.

**Possible fix**

Instead of women ovulation like a clockwork, make it a induced ovulation. And instead of the ovulation being induced by just sex, it also requires months of social grooming.

This way, bonding with a new partner would be too troublesome for the most part, so both sexes would rather stick with a single partner. Women might still benefit from lovers, but it is unlikely her primary partner would allow all his efforts to go to waste, so increase jealousy and mate guarding in men. Men could technically still get multiple partners (harems or cheating), but since they are doing the heavy lifting of getting the woman to ovulate, this would probably be rare

Plus, one of the explanations for periods is that is faster to just throw the thing away instead of absorb it like other mammals do. So if women won't be ovulating every month, you can also get rid of periods.

Comment: I like this answer. It gives a pretty solid ideal for how to ensure the world I want is created.

Answer (score 1):

**The culture. . . of EARTH.**

[image]

Having more than one long-term romantic partner is already vanishingly rare, at least where I come from. I have seen them on the telly, but I have never met anyone in such a union.

Perhaps the rich feel less bound by normal cultural standards. Perhaps it is easier for them to hide their extra partners.* But do they actually have them?

*Is it really though? The rich are better at keeping privacy but they also have more people trying to invade that privacy and write bad news articles about them.

Granted that makes it hard to answer the question of "how many polyamorous rich people are there?". If you took a celebrity at random, for example [Martin Clunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Clunes) I could not reliably tell you whether he has a secret second wife or husband.

But it is telling that I have heard many stories about famous people doing sexual assaults and acrimonious divorces. And loads of stories about celebrities saying the wrong thing online (super embarrasing btw). And the rich should be better at keeping these private too.

I can only imagine any polyamorousness would eventually get smeared on the tabloids and I'd hear about it. "Hey bro did you hear the gossip about Brad Pitt's second family?" Perhaps it would take ten years before the polyamorousness was found out. But I have never heard of that happening either. So I can only conclude it's rare.

Comment: Both Brad Pitt and Martin Clunes have had famous relationships with two people at once, so they're not great examples of successful just one long term romantic partner.

Comment: @NepeneNep Wikipedia says each has been married twice. Do you mean the new wives overlapped with the old wives at some stage? Did the old wives know about this?

Answer (score -1):

Well, to get society to be monogamous. heteronormativity, where monogamy is respected and enforced is something extremly recent. for most of history all classes of people have looked to mingle with more than one people. even if you had a main partner due to financial reason (mariage for wealth and such)   affaire have alway been a common occurence.

your best bet, if your not hellbent on keeping human as is, is to have your main race to be naturally enclined to mate for life instead of being by nature polyamourous, because at the end of the day, it's what's creat this situation.

religion & culture can also help you quite a lot in making sure that transgression are frowned uppon. if there is no societal way for you to have multiple relationship without being shuned, it is surely good enough for quite  a lot of people. TO make it work on the rich make it so that they loose all inehritance right and it is given to their younger sibling.

Comment: The question asks about suppressing [polyamory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyamory). It does not require monogamy. For example, a society where men use the services of prostitutes satisfies the requirements, as does a society where discreet adultery is acceptable. (And note that actually in our own real world polyamory is rare and not fully acceptable socially.)

Comment: Is there any culture or model to how to make your main race be naturally inclined to mate for life? That's the goal, but I'm looking more for how to do it, not just a statement that it should be done.